# Routing a URL to a php argument

Tags: php, html, regex, .htaccess, web

i have a URL which i would like to re-route in the following manner:

```
example.com/H4tX
```

to

```
example.com/game.php?id=h4tX
```

for this i have the following .htacces file in the cgi-bin folder of my domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ game.php?id=$1
```

However, if i try to go to example.com/H4tX, the page cannot be found. Did i miss something here? htaccess pretty much gives no feedback at all :/
Thanks, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` file is supposed to be at the root folder right next to your index.php file ( if you want to use it globaly for your site ) and **not** in any other folder.

If you put it in another folder, it will work only for that specific folder.

Comment: doesnt seem to work :/ ive copied the htacces file to the root folder(public_html) still no luck

Comment: Oh wait, it does work, thanks for the effort, i tried along with the solution above and that must've screwed it up the first time

Answer (score 2):

you are missing a /, try that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /game.php?id=$1
```